# Getting div to transition in from bottom, when in view

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions, jquery-waypoints

During research I found out that waypoints is a great way to check to see if a div is in view. So, I integrated it with my code. My issue is that the div that I am checking for `#review-main` is registering even when it is not in view.

As you will see in the snippet, I have two radio boxes. The `#review-main` div is within the Option 2 div. So when you click on the Option two radio input, that is when `#review-main` is actually in view.

Why is waypoints registering `#review-main` as in view when it isn't?

Also, what I am trying to do is get `#bundle-offer` to transition from off the screen to the bottom. I do not think I am doing this correctly either. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong with the `addClass` fadeUp?

```
#bundle-offer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -120px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  background: blue;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#bundle-offer.fadeUp {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(120px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(120px);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Below is a snippet.

```js
var package1 = $('#package1');
var package2 = $('#package2');
$('.product').on('change', function() {
  if (package1.is(':checked')) {
    console.log("Option - Package 1");
    $('#pack2-details').hide();
    $('#pack1-details').show();
  } else if (package2.is(':checked')) {
    console.log("Option - Package 2");
    $('#pack2-details').show();
    $('#pack1-details').hide();
  }
});
$('#review-main').waypoint(function() {
  // handler: function(direction) {
  //alert('You have scrolled to an entry.');
  $('#bundle-offer').addClass('fadeUp');
  console.log('Scrolled to waypoint!');
}, {
  offset: '100%'
});
```

```css
.check {
  display: none;
}

.wrap {
  background: green;
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
}

#bundle-offer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -120px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  background: blue;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#bundle-offer.fadeUp {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(120px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(120px);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<label>Option 1</label>
<input type="radio" class="product" id="package1">
<label>Option 2</label>
<input type="radio" class="product" id="package2">
<div id="pack1-details" class="check">
  <p>Package 1</p>
  <div class="wrap" id="pack1-details">
    Package 1 showing
  </div>
</div>
<div id="pack2-details" class="check">
  <p>Package 2</p>
  <div class="wrap" id="pack2-details">
    Package 2 showing
    <div id="review-main">
      <div id="bundle-offer"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```